# Why are `*.fmt` files in `/var`?

Tags: format-files

We see the following listing.

```
    [op@localhost pdftex]$ pwd
    /var/lib/texmf/web2c/pdftex
    [op@localhost pdftex]$ ls
    amstex.fmt   etex.fmt     mltex.fmt       pdfjadetex.fmt  texsis.fmt
    amstex.log   etex.log     mltex.log       pdfjadetex.log  texsis.log
    cont-en.fmt  jadetex.fmt  mptopdf.fmt     pdflatex.fmt    utf8mex.fmt
    cont-en.log  jadetex.log  mptopdf.log     pdflatex.log    utf8mex.log
    cslatex.fmt  latex.fmt    pdfcslatex.fmt  pdfmex.fmt      xmltex.fmt
    cslatex.log  latex.log    pdfcslatex.log  pdfmex.log      xmltex.log
    csplain.fmt  mex.fmt      pdfcsplain.fmt  pdftex.fmt
    csplain.log  mex.log      pdfcsplain.log  pdftex.log
    eplain.fmt   mllatex.fmt  pdfetex.fmt     pdfxmltex.fmt
    eplain.log   mllatex.log  pdfetex.log     pdfxmltex.log
```

Why, though? Are the `*.fmt` files specific to the host? I'd think
they'd be in `/usr/share/texmf-dist` with the rest of the TeX stuff.

I'm using TeX Live on Arch Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fmt files are typically in `texmf-var` or `var`. They are auto-generated. If you remove such a file then it is auto-generated again. The `texmf-dist` includes only the fixed stuff: the copy from distribution files. Auto-generated files belongs to "var stuff".

Moreover, there is `texmf-local` with the files analogical to `texmf-dist` but managed manually by system administrator. If new version of the distribution is installed (for example `texmf-dist` is removed and installed again) then `texmf-local` is kept unchanged. The `~/texmf/` is user variant of the `texmf-local` + `var`.

Comment: Perhaps also add that as they are memory dumps, they are specific to the host?

Comment: Yes, they are specific to the host and to the version of TeX engine. The `var` space was used to auto-generated PK bitmap fonts in old days of TeX too.

Comment: Why are they specific to the host? They are memory dumps?